# Actionscript to open URL in new window open new window but not fullscreen

Tags: flash

Actionscript to open URL in new window open new window but not fullscreen

Comment: Could you phrase that as a question? I'm not really sure what you mean. Which version of actionscript?

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are two ways to look at this - if you're using AS3 you can either you can use the navigateToURL method like so:

```
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.stackoverflow.com"), "_blank");
```

or you'll have to communicate out to Javascript and have it pop open a new window for you. If that's the case that question has been answered here: http://cartoonsmartblog.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/popup-window-from-flash-exact-sized-without-browser-buttons-or-scrollbar/

This kind of thing is a *really* common question - in the future you should make it a habit of hitting up google before you ask a question here.

Comment: Hey I thought this was still relevant and I used this answer in Jan 2016.  Don't knock him for asking!